# The link function in the directive does not draw a border AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

hey i'm trying to make a border for items listed with ng-repeat, i used the link function but i do not want to work, i do not draw a border and it only creates dashes.

**directive**

```
    (function(){
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      scope : {
        list : '='
      },
      template: '<div class="dire" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>', 
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
```

**demo**
https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/mqKVWY?editors=1111

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPEOyK?editors=1111

Comment: alphapilgrim did not work, dfsq I need this option with use link function :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div element is an inline object. You need to make it a `block` or `inline-block`element by using `display: block;`. This is not depending on your directive. It's CSS problem.

```
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

**>> [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZKMXy)**

Comment: thanks ! I have question to you what if I want make link function with addClass to child div??

Comment: Yes i know, but i only asking on future, you know .. :D what happend if... :P